# C Program to decode Morse code to text using spaces to detect words or sentences

Tags: c, whitespace, morse-code

I have an assignment that requires me to decode a Morse code string. The assignment specifies that:

**- There will be no space between a character (example between *.* and *-*)**

**- Each character is separated by 1 space**

**- Each word is separated by 4 space**

So far I have:

```
//Function to convert Morse code to text
char morsecode_to_text(char input[], int index){

int index_1 = 0, index_2 = 0, x = 0;
char output[100] = {'\0'};//Variable to keep output and later used to display text
char string[50] = {'\0'};//Variable to combine output

char *characters[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M","N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U",
                      "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"};


char *morsecode[] = {".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---", "-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",
                     ".-.","...","-","..-", "...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..", ".----","..---","...--","....-", ".....", "-....",
                     "--...","---..","----.","-----"};


while(input[index] < 1000){
    if(input[index] != '\0'){
        if(input[index] == '.' || input[index] == '-') {
            //Compare if input Morse code is similar to Morse code in array
            while(input[index] == '.' || input[index] == '-'){
                string[index_1] = input[index];
                index += 1;
                ++index_1;
            }//end of while loop

            for(index_2=0;index_2<36;index_2++){
                if(strcmp(string, morsecode[index_2]) == 0){
                    strcat(output, characters[index_2]);
                    x = 1;}
            }//end of for loop

        memset(string,0,sizeof(string));
        //Check for spaces
        }else if(input[index] == ' '){
            if(input[index + 1] == ' ') {
                if((input[index + 2] == ' ') && (input[index + 3] == ' ')){
                    strcat(output," ");
                    index += 4;
                }else{
                    strcpy(output, "FAIL - WRONG MORSE CODE");
                    break;}
            }else
                index++;

        }else if(input[index] == '\0' || input[index] == '\n'|| input[index] != '.' || input[index] != '-'){
            break;}
    }else
        break;
}//end of while loop

if (x == 1){
printf("MORSE CODE TRANSLATED : SUCCESS - %s", output);
}else{
    strcpy(output,"FAIL - WRONG MORSE CODE");
    printf("%s", output);
}

}//end of Function to convert Morse code to text

void main()
{
    char input[1000] = {'\0'}; //User input
    char choice = 'y'; //Amount of time user wants to replay
    int index = 0;

do{
    system("cls");
    printf("MORSE CODE TRANSLATOR PROGRAM\n");
    printf("\nPlease enter a Morse code string: ");
    fgets(input,1000,stdin);

    morsecode_to_text(input, index);

printf("\n\nDo you want to try again? (Press 'y' for Yes and 'n' for No): ");
scanf("%c", &choice);
getchar();
}while(choice == 'y');//end of while loop
}//end of void main
```

And my output was supposed to look like this:
[Example of Morse Code Translator Program execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdXbM.png)

But the space function does not work correctly and therefore it displays this: [Output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmVqZ.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Proposal: If you store your translation table to a *binary L/R tree* (e.g http://www.cranburyscouts.org/MorseTree.htm) you'll be ending up with a much less complicated decoding algorithm.

Comment: I can't help but think that the two arrays `char *characters[] = {"A", …};` and `char *morsecode[] = {".-", …};` would be better represented as two arrays of a structure type along the lines of `struct Morse { char *symbol; char *morse; };` and then using an array of that structure type. A structure certainly makes it easier to ensure that the right Morse is associated with the right symbol.

Answer (score -1):

a very simple one using your lookup tables

one non `.` or '-' - separates chars

more than one space - words.

```
const char *getLetter(const char *morse, int *ch)
{
    char coded[10];
    const char *startpos = morse;

    while(*morse && *morse!= '.' && *morse != '-')
        morse++;
    if(!*morse) return NULL;
    startpos = morse;
    while(*morse && (*morse== '.' || *morse == '-'))
        morse++;
    if ((startpos - morse) > 9) return NULL;
    strncpy(coded, startpos, morse - startpos);
    coded[morse - startpos] = 0;
    *ch = -1;
    for(int index = 0; index < sizeof(morsecode) / sizeof(morsecode[0]); index++)
    {
        if(!strcmp(morsecode[index], coded))
        {
            *ch = characters[index][0];
            break;
        }
    }
    return morse;
}

int IsSpace(const char *morse)
{
    return *morse && *morse ==' ' && *(morse + 1) == ' ';
}

int main(void)
{
    char *morsestring = ".- -... -.-. -..     .- -... -.-. -.. ----------";
    int ch = 0;
    const char *nextpos = morsestring;
    while((nextpos = getLetter(nextpos, &ch)) != NULL)
    {
        if(ch == -1)
        {
            printf(" *ERR* ");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c%s", ch, IsSpace(nextpos) ? " " : "");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

//See Easy instructions and have Fun of the Program

using namespace std;
void  convert(char s[]);
void clrscr()
{
    system("@cls||clear");

}

int main()
{
    clrscr();

    char string[100];

    cout<<"INSTRUCTIONS : \n\n";
    cout<<"1. Enter leaving single SPACE     (like) : To enter MAN -> -- .- -. ";
    cout<<endl<<"2. To Give SPACE, Enter s (small s) with Space (like) : To Enter MR A -> -- .-. s .-";
    cout<<endl<<endl<<"SIMPLE !";
    getch();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter the Code to Convert into STRING  : \n";
    gets(string);


    cout<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"Converting ....";
    getch();
    clrscr();

    //for(int i =0 ; i < strlen(string) ; i++)

    convert(string);



    getch();
    return 0;

}


void  convert(char s[])
{

    int j=0;
    int i=0;
    int c=0;
    int add=0;

    char a[10];
    char f[100];


    while(s[j] != '\0')
    {   

        c=0;

        while (c != 5)
        {
            a[c]='\0';
            c++;
        }

        i=0;
        while( s[j] != ' ' && s[j] != '\0')
        {
            a[i] = s[j];
            j++;
            i++;
        }
        if(s[j]== ' ' ){j++;}


        a[i+1]='\0';

        if(strcmp(a,".-") == 0)
        {
            f[add]='A';
            add++;
            f[add]='\0';
        }
        else if(strcmp(a,"-...") == 0){f[add]= 'B'; add++; f[add]='\0';}
        else if(strcmp(a,"-.-.") == 0){f[add]= 'C'; add++; f[add]='\0';}
        else if(strcmp(a,"-..") == 0){f[add]= 'D'; add++; f[add]='\0';}

        else if(strcmp(a,".") == 0){f[add]= 'E'; add++; f[add]='\0';}
        else if(strcmp(a,"..-.") == 0){f[add]= 'F'; add++; f[add]='\0';}
        else if(strcmp(a,"--.") == 0){f[add]= 'G'; add++; f[add]='\0';}
        else if(strcmp(a,"....") == 0){f[add]= 'H'; add++; f[add]='\0';}
        else if(strcmp(a,"..") == 0){f[add]= 'I'; add++; f[add]='\0';}

        else if(strcmp(a,".---") == 0){f[add]= 'J'; add++; f[add]='\0';}
        else if(strcmp(a,"-.-") == 0){f[add]= 'K'; add++; f[add]='\0';}
        else if(strcmp(a,".-..") == 0){f[add]= 'L'; add++; f[add]='\0';}
        else if(strcmp(a,"--") == 0){f[add]= 'M'; add++; f[add]='\0';}

        else if(strcmp(a,"-.") == 0){f[add]= 'N'; add++; f[add]='\0';}
        else if(strcmp(a,"---") == 0){f[add]= 'O'; add++; f[add]='\0';}
        else if(strcmp(a,".--.") == 0){f[add]= 'P'; add++; f[add]='\0';}
        else if(strcmp(a,"--.-") == 0){f[add]= 'Q'; add++; f[add]='\0';}

        else if(strcmp(a,".-.") == 0){f[add]= 'R'; add++; f[add]='\0';}
        else if(strcmp(a,"...") == 0){f[add]= 'S'; add++; f[add]='\0';}
        else if(strcmp(a,"-") == 0){f[add]= 'T'; add++; f[add]='\0';}
        else if(strcmp(a,"..-") == 0){f[add]= 'U'; add++; f[add]='\0';}

        else if(strcmp(a,"...-") == 0){f[add]= 'V'; add++; f[add]='\0';}
        else if(strcmp(a,".--") == 0){f[add]= 'W'; add++; f[add]='\0';}
        else if(strcmp(a,"-..-") == 0){f[add]= 'X'; add++; f[add]='\0';}
        else if(strcmp(a,"-.--") == 0){f[add]= 'Y'; add++; f[add]='\0';}
        else if(strcmp(a,"--..") == 0){f[add]= 'Z'; add++; f[add]='\0';}
        else if(strcmp(a,"s") == 0 ){f[add]=' '; add++; f[add]='\0';}








    }


    cout<<f;


}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation for your code to your post.  Either that, or change the variable names to make it understandable.  Also, the OP was talking about C, not C++.